# Redirect all no http request to https+www except subdomains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have a bit of problem here while creating .htaccess file for proper redirection.
I need to redirect all requests to https with www except subdomains.

**This is the scenario:**

```
http://example.com-> https://www.example.com
https://example.com-> https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com-> https://www.example.com
http://subdomain.example.com-> http://subdomain.example.com[unchanged]
or
http://subdomain.example.com-> https://www.example.com/sites/subdomain
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add this to the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks jon, does it handle 
http://subdomain.example.com-> http://subdomain.example.com[unchanged]
or
http://subdomain.example.com-> https://www.example.com/sites/subdomain